# My repeater is not displaying the text, have I missed something?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater generates LinkButtons

Here is the repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptBreadCrumb" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <asp:LinkButton CssClass="process-breadcrumb" ID="lnkBrdCrmb" runat="server" OnCommand="lnkWeb_Click" />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and here is the codebehind code:

```
var items = new List<object> {};
var urlList = weburl.ParseUrl();
foreach (var url in urlList)
{
    using (var site = new SPSite(url))
    {
        using (var selectedWeb = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            items.Add(new { Text = selectedWeb.Title + " > ", Url = url });
        }
    }
}
rptBreadCrumb.DataSource = items;
rptBreadCrumb.DataBind();
```

Am I missing something? Beacuse its not displaying any text. The linkbuttons gets generated, but there is no text. How can I make sure that the linkbuttons gets it?

Comment: Where is your code in codebehind? Ondatabound() of the repeater?

Comment: because you do not write any statement that print's any text.....? Or you may be missing the Text property of LinkButton

Comment: Try using Text = <%# Eval(YourPropertyName) %> in your aspx file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `Repeaters` `ItemDataBound` event to set the url and text.

aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptBreadCrumb" OnItemDataBound="rptBreadCrumb_DataBound" >
...
```

codebehind:

```
protected void rptBreadCrumb_DataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        LinkButton lnkBrdCrmb = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnkBrdCrmb");
        // get the anonymous type's properties via DataBinder.Eval
        string text = (string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Text");
        string url = (string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Url");
        lnkBrdCrmb.Text = text;
        lnkBrdCrmb.PostBackUrl = url;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a great example, but what should I do at // get the anonymous type's properties via DataBinder.Eval, I dont understand that :/

Comment: @Obsivus: nothing, it should work as it is. That's just a comment why i'm using `DataBinder.Eval` in codebehind which is very unusual. The reason is that you're using an anonymous type as datasource which i can access only with reflection, so i've used `DataBinder.Eval`.